# Normal bump problem

Tags: bump

I've started to learn Blender by myself with all tutos on the web. I really enjoy Blender.
First sorry for my english...
I have a problem to make a bump on the normal node.
So I try witha very simple cube. Il I put a checker on the normal node the cube become b&w and I don't "see" bump.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I add a normal map node I see the cube grey and white but still no bump...

[image]
[image]

What have I missed? I have Blender 2.8 and filmic add-on.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:
Use your texture as Height Map into a bump node (shift+a > vector > bump) instead using it as color input in a Normal Map node.

Explanation:
The Bump Node's Height Map input works with B&W images where black is 0 and white is 1 (like your checker texture Fac output), Normal Maps are instead RGB images in which the intensity of every channel (R, G, B) is equal to the amount of bump on the corresponding axis (X, Y, Z).

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I tried and it's ok. But the bump effect is very limited even if I try to put the strength over 1.000. Can I try to play with an other value to boost the bump? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Riccardo's answer, with a completely b&w picture you won't fake much volume. But you can try is:

- Create a b&w checker picture.
- Use a software like CrazyBump to create a bump or a normal map, it will blur your picture, thus give more volume. You can also simply do it with an image editor, like picture below:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer I will try this :)

Comment: Is that 2.8...? :D

Comment: yes   ;)   still have bugs though

Comment: After a lot of try, I've understand that what I wanted was a displacement map (with noise input in height) in the displacement node of the material output. And check that Cycles is active cause when it's Eevee I see no result... Thank you for your answers.